3.5mm headset mic not detected in Acer Predator Helios 16 laptop with ALC245 model running Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
I am using Acer Predator Helios 16 laptop with ALC245 model running Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS version. this is confirmed using As suggested by all here to add those options lines in alsa-base.conf file, i tried both individually. And of course various solutions from others as well like...and almost all solutions from various threads here in this forum. None worked and hence opening a new thread for this problem.
options snd-hda-intel model=alc245,laptop-amic (for my exact ALC model)
and 
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
and 
in combination of these both.

But after reboots, none worked and none detected my 3.5mm headset microphone. It beautifully works in windows 11. this confirms that my laptop's 3.5mm jack is fully capable of a headset with stereo microphone.
I tried many other options too as well like removing pulse audio, purging pulse audio, reinstalling it back, reloading alsa, reloading pulse, installing pavu control, changing settings there. But none worked for my laptop model.
Here are few more details to understand this situation better:
hkp@aph16:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

hkp@aph16:~$ uname -r
6.8.0-45-generic

    hkp@aph16:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDA Digital (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Loopback [Loopback], device 0: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 2: Loopback [Loopback], device 1: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7

hkp@aph16:~$ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 169
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: hkp
Host Name: aph16
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 1.0.7)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.platform-snd_aloop.0.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__source
Cookie: 07a0:0790

hkp@aph16:~$ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Nvidia GPU a7 HDMI/DP
Codec: Realtek ALC245
Codec: Intel Alderlake HDMI

I am now in high frustration mode, as i sieved all internet for solutions and tried all with no success to get an age old technology of 3.5mm jack running on advanced Ubuntu version!!!
APPRECIATE ANY HELP TO SOLVE THIS SIMPLE ISSUE AND TO COOL DOWN MY FRUSTRATION!

not even a single reply in these 15 days! wow! is this issue so clueless to all!?!?!?
